# R - apriori() support vs coverage?

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I am using apriori to find assocaition rules and I am running into an issue:

| rule           | support           | confidence   | lift            | coverage       |
|---------------|--------------------|------------------|--------------|-------------------|
| {A} => {B} | 8.616999e-05 | 0.01502544 | 19.11896 | 0.005734940 |
| {A} => {C} | 8.944227e-05 | 0.01559602 | 49.05084 | 0.005734940 |

**The manual states that Coverage:**
Provides the generic function and the needed S4 method to calculate the coverage (support of the
left-hand-side) of rules.

For a small ruleset coverage is equal to support.  Why does coverage differ from support for large rulesets?

Answer (score 2):

From the man page for `interestMeasure`:

*"coverage", cover, LHS-support Support of the left-hand-side of the rule, i.e., supp(X).  A measure of to how often the rule can be applied. Range: [0, 1]*

So, coverage is greater or (in some rare cases) equal to the support of the rule.

Sorry that this is somewhat confusing in the documentation, but, you know, we all love to maintain documentation. I will improve the documentation for coverage in the next release...

Answer (score 0):

The **Support** of the rule is the probability of all items in that rule occurring together in a transaction:

> `Support(A=>B) = P(A U B)`

The **Confidence** of the rule is the conditional probability of the consequent given the antecedent:

> `Confidence(A=>B) = P(B|A)`

The **Coverage** of the rule is the probability for the antecedent alone in the entire dataset:

> `Coverage(A=>B) = P(A)`

Coverages tells how frequent your antecedent is in the dataset. It thus gives an idea of how often the rule could be applied.

If a consequent (B) always occurs when the antecedent (A) also occurs, then the Coverage will equal the Support for that rule, and the Confidence will be 1. It means that the rule is applied 100% of the times that the antecedent occurs.
This is more likely to happen in small datasets, with only few cases. In large datasets, it could be seen almost a "law" rather than a rule!

It also denotes that Coverage can be calculated from dividing Support by Confidence. This derives from the formulas above, considering that A and B are not independent events:

> IF `Support = P(A U B) --> P(A) * P(B|A)` [for non-independent events]

> AND `Confidence(A=>B) = P(B|A)`

> THEN `Coverage = Support / Confidence`
>
> `Coverage = P(A) * P(B|A) / P(B|A)`
>
> `Coverage = P(A)`

You can confirm this from your screenshot above, eg. for rule {A} => {B}:

> `8.616999e-05 / 0.01502544 = 0.005735`